# Mandatory fields in the html form using PHP PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I have a html form where i want 3 fields to be mandatory. If the user doesn't fill any one of those fields, then the form shouldn't be submitted and it should tell the user to fill in the mandatory one's. I've used PDO and i dont know how to do it. If someone could help me. Down below i've given both my html and php files.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Data Insertion</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><span class="Error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="su.php"> 
<h2>Please Fill In Details</h2>
<label for="name">Name </label>
<input type="text" Placeholder="Enter your name" name="name" id="name" />
<span class="Error">*</span>
<br />
<br />
<label for="age">Age </label>
<input type="text" name="age" id="age" placeholder="Enter your age"  />
<br />
<br />
<label for="mailid">MailId </label>
 <input type="text" name="mailid" id="mailid" placeholder="Enter your Mail   Id" />
<span class="Error">*</span>
<br />
<br />
<label for="gender">Gender </label>
<br />
<label for="male">Male </label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="Male" id="male" />
<label for="female">Female </label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="Female" id="female" />
<br />
<br />
<label for="qualification">Qualification </label>
<select name="qualification" value="Qualification" id="qualification">
<option value="B.E">SSLC</option>
<option value="P.G">HSC</option>
<option value="SSLC">UG</option>
<option value="HSC">PG</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<label for="hobbies">Hobbies </label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="hobbies" value="Cricket" />Cricket
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="hobbies" value="Music" />Music
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="hobbies" value="Swimming" />Swimming
<br /><br />
<label for="textarea">Address </label>
<br />
<textarea name="address" id="textarea" rows="15" cols="30"></textarea>
<span class="Error">*</span>
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $servername = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=testing", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $age = $_POST['age'];
            $mailid = $_POST['mailid'];
            $gender = $_POST['qualification'];
            $hobbies = $_POST['address'];
            if($name !='' || $mailid !='' || $address !=''){
        $sql = "Insert into user (Name, Age, MailId, Gender, Qualification, Hobbies, Address) 
        values ('".$_POST["name"]."', '".$_POST["age"]."', '".$_POST["mailid"]."', '".$_POST["gender"]."', '".$_POST["qualification"]."', '".$_POST["hobbies"]."', '".$_POST["address"]."')";
        $conn->exec($sql);
        echo "Thank you for registering";
            } else {
                echo "<p>Insertion failed <br/> Please enter the required fields !";
            }}
    }
catch(PODException $e)
{
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: You have to use javascript for that.

Comment: even you can use html5 property required.

Comment: I want to do that with PHP. Don't want to use the 'required property'.

Comment: Any clue of how i can do it using javascript?

Comment: Also, you have to fix your html. You can't repeat ids like you have. You also need to add [] to the name of elements whose value you'd like to dump into an array. A far more typical method of registering is to just allow entry of the required information, along with a notice informing the user of the options available to them on their options page. There are so many tutorials that show how to check the values of a form before allowing a send to occur, I'm more inclined to think you didn't look than your google foo is down for maintenance.. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: @enhzflep Thank you. I got the output. I just have to modify few things as you said. Thanks again

Comment: @NagaNaveen - you're welcome. You should also look into using PDO properly. As it is, you're concatenating strings together to construct your query. You shouldn't do that with query strings - `parameterized queries` are one of the many benefits of PDO, ease with which you can use different databases is the other biggie. Try having a look at the following docs to bind the parameters to your query. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php - example 1 has what you need. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the html 5 attribute "required" on all the required input elements. For example

```
<input type="text" Placeholder="Enter your name" name="name" id="name" required />
```

You should also check the POST variables in the php code though, as this doesn't really prevent someone from abusing your service. Ex.

```
if(!isset($_POST['somevar'])) {
    // Do insert
}
```

Comment: I have already done it with html 5 required property. Now my doubt is how do i do it using PHP PDO.

Comment: What do you mean in PHP or in PDO? I think you are confusing / making things harder then they are. If you mean PDO you should probably look into using prepared statements for your query since it is alot safer.

Answer (score 0):

In html You should use javascript (e.g. jQuery) to control onsubmit event and validate if mandatory fields are filled with proper values, check this link: [jQuery.submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

In php You should check and validate each var before create and execute query. Simple article about it is here: [Sanitize and Validate Data with PHP Filters](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters--net-2595)
This would be good for the start I think ;)

Query string should contain placeholders and then statement should be prepared for execution, check this link:
[PDOStatement::bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)